# ListView.builder with Widget at the bottom of a SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need a SingleChildScrollView with messages at the bottom.

[image]

I found a solution for bottom alignment in SingleChildScrollView [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66820328/5057736):

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('AppBar'),
        ),
        body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: constraints.maxWidth, minHeight: constraints.maxHeight),
                  child: IntrinsicHeight(
                    child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: [
                          Text('header'),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.green,
                              child: Text('body'),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text('footer'),
                           // MY CODE STARTS
                           ListView.builder(
                             itemCount: 2,
                             itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                               return Text("a " + index.toString());
                             }
                           )
                           // MY CODE ENDS
                        ]
                    ),
                  )
              )
          );
        })
    );
  }
}
```

However, when I try to add `ListView.builder` to this solution I get:

```
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderViewport does not support returning intrinsic dimensions.

Calculating the intrinsic dimensions would require instantiating every child of the viewport, which defeats the point of viewports being lazy.

If you are merely trying to shrink-wrap the viewport in the main axis direction, consider a RenderShrinkWrappingViewport render object (ShrinkWrappingViewport widget), which achieves that effect without implementing the intrinsic dimension API.
```

Could anyone say how to fix it?

Comment: try adding `shrinkWrap: true` to the list view

Comment: @Yahya If I add `shrinkWrap: true` I get `RenderShrinkWrappingViewport does not support returning intrinsic dimensions.`

Comment: Okay then try adding some height constraint to the ListView such as `SizedBox(height: 200, child: ListView.builder(),)` or even try wrapping it with Expanded.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Expanded` inside `SingleChildScrollView` will get infinite height, It would be better using top Level LayoutBuilder constrains on inner widget. Also the LisView desire infinite height.

As for the UI you are trying to get, It can be done by this, You might not need two scrollable widget.

```dart
body: LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text('header'),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                  Text("a " + index.toString())

              // MY CODE ENDS

              ),
        ),
        Text('footer'),
      ],
    );
  },
),
```

Also Using customScrollView provide more flexibility,

```dart
return Scaffold(
  bottomNavigationBar: TextFormField(),
  body: LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, constraints) {
      return CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            title: Text("title"),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Text('top item'),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (context, index) {
                return Text("a " + index.toString());
              },
            ),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Text('End item'),
          )
        ],
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

Actually, it can be done many ways.

Not recommended way,

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('AppBar'),
    ),
    body: LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
                minWidth: constraints.maxWidth,
                minHeight: constraints.maxHeight),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [
                Text('header'),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: Text('body'),
                ),

                Text('footer'),
                // MY CODE STARTS
                ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true, //not recommended

                    itemCount: 211,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Text("a " + index.toString());
                    })
                // MY CODE ENDS
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am testing your first solution. I need `ListView.builder` under footer (or instead of the footer).  By other words ListView items must be at the bottom of the scroll view. Could you show how to to it, as I still can't make it work?

Comment: Can you include an image that you are trying to archive

Comment: I added picture to my question. Please, note, that in my code I add `ListView.builder` AFTER `Expanded` node, but you add `ListView.builder` IN `Expanded` node.

Comment: You need two scrollable widgets, one for full body or topPart? Another one just for message box?

Comment: Let's consider that I have `SingleChildScrollView` without fixed height (as it must take all space it can take) and I need to put my messages at the bottom. The solution how to do it I found. I just need to add my `ListView.builder` at the bottom.

Comment: Did you test the second widget where I am using `bottomNavigationBar`

Comment: I tested but I wouldn't like to use it. As this is not my project and they don't use `slivers`. So, if it is possible, I would like to make it work using approaches that are used in the project.

Comment: Please, just help me to add `ListView.builder`. I can't understand what is wrong with it.

Comment: Try last one, But it is too expensive. also discuss with others team members to follow slivers, like using `IntrinsicHeight`, srinkwrap is the first thing I will avoid any cost

Comment: Thank you. I tried you last solution. However, if you reduce itemCount: 211 to `itemCount: 2` then items won't be at the bottom of the `SingleChildScrollView`.

Comment: This is really getting harder with singleChildScrollView, I think it didnt created for this. As for the UI, you can use top level single scrollable widget

Comment: I checked you solution with `slivers`, it also doesn't align messages at the bottom. Did you test it to get results as I showed in the picture?

Answer (score -1):

It here:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  List<String> listData = [
    "Item",
    "Item",
    "Item",
    "Item",
    "Item",
    "Item",
    "Item",
    "Item",
    "Item",
    "Item",
    "Item",
    "Item",
    "Item",
    "Item",
    "Item",
    "Item",
    "Item",
    "Item"
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('AppBar'),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: listData.length + 2,
          itemExtent: 100,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            if (index == 0) {
              return Container(
                child: Text('Header'),
              );
            }
            if (index == listData.length + 1) {
              return Container(
                child: Text('Footer'),
              );
            }
            return Container(
              child: Text('Item at $index'),
            );
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: more "natural" solution would be to use `CustomScrollView` with three slivers: `SliverToBoxAdapter` + `SliverList` + `SliverToBoxAdapter`